# Abstract base class in Dart

Tags: oop, dart, abstract-class, base-class

I have been programming in Java for nearly two years but I am now more shifting to web programming and thus to Javascript, or in my case to Dart. For a project I'm working on I would like to have abstract base classes, just I would have in Java. I have been looking on the internet but I can't find anything on abstract classes at all for Dart. I only found [this article from the dart lang site on mixins](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/), that in an example uses the abstract keyword for a class. But I don't really understand the mixins principle.

**Could somebody translate this easy Java abstract base class example to Dart** so that I can have a basic understanding on how it would be done in Dart? The example covers *abstract base class* (ofcourse, with abstract methods), *polymorphism*, *casting objects*, *method overloading* (in this case it is the constructor), *calling super-constructor* and *calling overloaded own constructor*.

```java
// Abstract base class
abstract class Vehicle {
    protected final int maxSpeed;
    protected int speed;
    
    Vehicle() {
        this(0);
    }
    
    Vehicle(int maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        speed = 0;
    }
    
    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }
    
    abstract void accelerate();
    abstract void brake();
}

// Subclass of Vehicle, the abstract baseclass
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public final int doors;
    
    Car(int maxSpeed, int doors) {
        super(maxSpeed);
        this.doors = doors;
    }
    
    @Override
    void accelerate() {
        if (speed>maxSpeed) {
            speed = maxSpeed;
            return;
        }
        speed += 2;
    }

    @Override
    void brake() {
        if (speed - 2 < 0) {
            speed = 0;
            return;
        }
        this.speed -= 2;
    }
}
```

And how would this easy implementation look like?

```java
// Polymorphism
Vehicle car = new Car(180, 4);

// Casting
int doors = ((Car)car).doors;

// Calling abstract method
car.accelerate();
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually it does become simpler in dart (https://dartpad.dartlang.org/37d12fa77834c1d8a172)

```
// Abstract base class
abstract class Vehicle {
  final int maxSpeed;
  int speed = 0;

  Vehicle([this.maxSpeed = 0]);

  void accelerate();
  void brake();
}

// Subclass of Vehicle, the abstract baseclass
class Car extends Vehicle {
  final int doors;

  Car(int maxSpeed, this.doors) : super(maxSpeed);

  @override
  void accelerate() {
    if (speed > maxSpeed) {
      speed = maxSpeed;
      return;
    }
    speed += 2;
  }

  @override
  void brake() {
    if (speed - 2 < 0) {
      speed = 0;
      return;
    }
    this.speed -= 2;
  }
}

main() {
  // Polymorphism
  Vehicle car = new Car(180, 4);

  // Casting
  int doors = (car as Car).doors;

  // Calling abstract method
  car.accelerate();
}
```

Answer (score 45):

I would take a look at the [Language tour, there's a whole section on abstract classes](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#abstract-classes)

Key points:

- Abstract classes in Dart have to be marked as `abstract`.
- An abstract class can have "abstract methods", you just have to omit the body
- A concrete class can mark itself as "implementing" the abstract class' contract with the keyword `implements`. This will force you to implement all the expected behavior on the concrete class, but it won't inherit the abstract class' provided methods' implementation.
- You can extend an abstract class with the keyword `extends`, and the concrete class will inherit all possible behavior of the abstract class.

That's pretty much it!

Also, you might want to take a look at mixins, there's a section below the one I have you in the Language tour.

Comment: DO we have abstract properties in dart?

Comment: The "omit the body" did the trick! thanks.